# HTTP REST Response not complete in Apache Karaf under Windows

Tags: java, rest, jersey, apache-karaf, karaf

my setup: Apache Karaf 3.0.3, our web app with jersey 1.x, Postman extension in chrome

Linux: I call one of our REST services and get xml response back, everything's OK
Windows 7: I call the same REST service and I get xml response not complete in this way:

expected response body < 8kB, response is nothing, 0kB, no xml
   8kB < expected response body < 16kB, response is trimmed to 8kB
   16kB < expected response body < 24kB, response is trimmed to 16kB
   24kB < expected response body < 32kB, response is trimmed to 24kB
   ...etc...

Conclusion: we're getting here these 8kB times something long xml blocks, but only in WINDOWS. Has anybody come across this weird issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flushing streams and streamwriter helped. Issue solved.